# Auto Increment ID in XML File

Tags: c#, asp.net

Could someone help me do this?
I wish he auto-increment, but he does not.
Could you help me do this?

My code is:

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath(@"Participantes.xml"));


    XmlElement newElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ID" **/* this is need auto-increment */**);
    XmlElement xmlNome = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Nome");
    XmlElement xmlClass = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Classe");
    XmlElement xmlFaccao = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Facção");
    XmlElement xmlLevel = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Level");


    xmlNome.InnerText = this.TextBox_I1.Text.Trim();
    xmlClass.InnerText = this.Class_I1.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();
    xmlFaccao.InnerText = this.Faccao.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();
    xmlLevel.InnerText = this.TextBox_lvl.Text.Trim();

    newElement.AppendChild(xmlNome);
    newElement.AppendChild(xmlClass);
    newElement.AppendChild(xmlFaccao);
    newElement.AppendChild(xmlLevel);

    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newElement);
    xmlDoc.Save(Server.MapPath(@"Participantes.xml"));
```

Anyone can help-me?
Anyone know how this?

__*_*__*_*__*_*_ EDIT 09/05/2012 ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

Solution:

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath(@"Participantes.xml"));


        var x = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("ID");
        int Max = 0;
        foreach (XmlElement item in x)
        {
            int ultimoID = Convert.ToInt32(item.GetAttribute("value"));
            if (ultimoID > Max)
            {
                Max = ultimoID;
            }
        }
        Max++;


        XmlElement newElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ID");
        newElement.SetAttribute("value", Max.ToString());
        XmlElement xmlNome = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Nome");
        XmlElement xmlClass = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Classe");
        XmlElement xmlFaccao = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Facção");
        XmlElement xmlLevel = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Level");


        xmlNome.InnerText = this.TextBox_I1.Text.Trim();
        xmlClass.InnerText = this.Class_I1.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();
        xmlFaccao.InnerText = this.Faccao.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();
        xmlLevel.InnerText = this.TextBox_lvl.Text.Trim();

        newElement.AppendChild(xmlNome);
        newElement.AppendChild(xmlClass);
        newElement.AppendChild(xmlFaccao);
        newElement.AppendChild(xmlLevel);

        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newElement);
        xmlDoc.Save(Server.MapPath(@"Participantes.xml"));
```

Use Attributes...
Because we have to follow the standard XML.
Select ID to set value with GetElementsByTagName!
Use foreach to verify Attribute "value" and insert +1 using SetAttribute

Comment: Do you have an example of how you'd like your resulting XML to look?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
int iID = 0;

XmlElement newElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ID_" + iID++.ToString())
```

And the rest is the same...

I've added the "ID_" because I'm not sure if a XML tag name can start with a number

Comment: This is return this:

  <ID_**0**>
    <Nome>Nome</Nome>
    <Classe>Classe</Classe>
    <Facção>Facção</Facção>
    <Level>60</Level>
  </ID_0>